Render_template not doing anything
I was having issues with render_template as part of a function in a larger program. It wouldn't launch the html file that i passed to it as an argument. I stripped everything out and it is still not doing anything. Not getting any errors, verified that html file is in the templates folder, as well as specified the folder via app = Flask(name, template_folder='../templates').
Below is the python code:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from replit import web

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('renderindex.html',username=web.auth.name,userid=web.auth.user_id)

Below is the html code:
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Templating</h1>
    <!-- This is the jinja syntax to use variables passed in from render_template. -->
    <h2>Hello, {{ username }}!</h2>
    <p>Your Replit UserID is {{ userid }}.</p>
</main>
</body>

Project Structure:
Documents
   static\
   templates\
         renderindex.html
   rendertest.py

Snippet of the problem from full program:
import requests
import jwt
import datetime
import time
import json
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates\\')

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return open('webpage.html').read()

@app.route('/store_values', methods=['POST'])
def store_values():
    data = request.get_json()
    production_order = data['productionOrder']


print("Production Order:", production_order)

production_order = "P50012960"
# Call the function to make API requests
response_data = make_api_requests(production_order)
query_results = json.loads(response_data)
print("Query Results:", query_results)
# You can return a response if needed
return(display_results(query_results))


@app.route('/')
def display_results(query_results):
    return render_template('results.html', data=query_results)


def make_api_requests(production_order):
    # Your API request code here
    url = 'confidential'
    authorization_response = requests.post(
            url,
            data={
               ###confidential
            }
        )

if authorization_response.status_code == 200:
    print('Connected to the API successfully')
    #print('Response:', authorization_response.text)
else:
    print('Failed to connect to the API. Status code:', authorization_response.status_code)

authorization_data = authorization_response.json()
access_token = authorization_data["access_token"]

print("ACCESS TOKEN:\n")
print(access_token)

base_url = 'confidential' 
sql_query = "confidential"

# Construct the complete URL
url = f"{base_url}/jobs/"

# Set up the request headers
aheaders = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
aheaders['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'  ##jb
aheaders['accept'] = 'application/json'  ##jb

# Make the request to execute the SQL query (THIS WORKS)
response = requests.post(url, headers=aheaders, data=sql_query)  ##jb

# (THIS WORKS)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Query executed successfully')
    print('Response:', response.json())
elif response.status_code == 202:    ##added elif :status code 202 = running
    print('query is running')
    print('Response:', response.json())
else:
    print('Failed to execute the query. Status code:', response.status_code)

data = response.json()
queryId = data["queryId"]
path = data["location"]
status = data["status"]

result_url = f"{base_url}/jobs/{queryId}/result/"
status_url = f"{base_url}/jobs/{queryId}/status/"

time.sleep(5)
#print('Response:', response.json())

# Make a GET request to retrieve the query results
status_response = requests.get(status_url, params={"offset": 0, "limit": 100}, headers=aheaders)
time.sleep(2)
result_response = requests.get(result_url, params={"offset": 0, "limit": 100}, headers=aheaders)
time.sleep(2)
print("Result response", result_response.status_code)
print("Status response", status_response.status_code)
# Check if the request was successful
if result_response.status_code == 200:
    print('Query results retrieved successfully')
    print('Response:', result_response.text)
    # Here, you can parse/process the query results based on the response format (e.g., JSON, CSV)
else:
    print('Failed to retrieve query results. Status code:', result_response.status_code)
    print('Response:', result_response.text)
return result_response.text

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    template_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'templates')
    app.template_folder = template_folder
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TxtPathCurrentFile = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    TxtPathCurrentDir = os.path.dirname(TxtPathCurrentFile)
    TxtPathTemplatesDir = os.path.join(TxtPathCurrentDir, 'templates')
    app.template_folder = TxtPathTemplatesDir
    #optional to see webpage
    #webbrowser.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
    app.run(debug=False)


Out of the blue, is this deployed as an .exe in your larger implementation?

@sgdva no it is not

Did you set flask to run at the end? if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug=False)

That fixed it thank you. In the larger program, I have that line of code at the bottom of the entire program, should I also add it to the function in which the render_template is called?

Nope, only on your final one :)

well in that case I am still getting the issue in the larger program! I will update the code here so you can see

Hmm interesting, probably is because is losing the reference, if it works on the calling script, leave it there, see my answer to see if that gives you a better reference for this :)

Solution
Whenever you are working with Flask, you need to run the instance itself at the end.
As an additional note: I strongly suggest the following implementation as this considers if flask is being packed in an exe.
#in your case since app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates'), replace ObjFlask by app
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    template_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'templates')
    ObjFlask.template_folder = template_folder
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TxtPathCurrentFile = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    TxtPathCurrentDir = os.path.dirname(TxtPathCurrentFile)
    TxtPathTemplatesDir = os.path.join(TxtPathCurrentDir, 'templates')
    ObjFlask.template_folder = TxtPathTemplatesDir
    #optional to see webpage
    #webbrowser.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
    ObjFlask.run(debug=False)


I put that at the bottom of the program but am still having the same issue. I will upload the entire code

I may be wrong but I think the main program is using flask as well right? However the flask that you use for render_template('renderindex.html is a different instance, so that one needs to be initialized as well (in addition to the main one calling)

I'm sorry, but could you show me where in the code to add this?

You forgot the return keyword.
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('renderindex.html',username=web.auth.name,userid=web.auth.user_id)


I did indeed but the issue persists. I've edited the code so many times trying to figure out what's causing it and forgot to put the return keyword back. Same result though

It seems like the path to your templates folder is set incorrectly. If you use the specified folder structure, it is not necessary to assign the template_folder attribute. If you still want to assign it, I think ./templates is the appropriate value.

I've made both changes in previous iterations but the same issue persists

I've also verified file permissions on the html file are all correct
